# Cups admin user and password Saucy

Tags: printing, cups-lpd

I can't change settings on my cups printer. He asks me for a username and password i already added for me the usergroup lpadmin . But nothing changes after a restart of cups.
Still asking me for username and password and my user is not working.

Comment: I am using saucy and my uid/pwd work for my cups. Is your user in sudo group as well? How are you accessing cups? (http://127.0.0.1:631 ?) and what is the error output in (e.g.) `tail -f /var/log/syslog`?

Comment: Just adding and removing of colord profiles and then this:
Jan 23 14:32:25 ubu anacron[1011]: Job `cron.daily' terminated
Jan 23 14:32:25 ubu anacron[1011]: Normal exit (1 job run)
Jan 23 14:37:36 ubu kernel: [ 1493.123196] type=1400 audit(1390484256.874:87): apparmor="DENIED" operation="file_lock" parent=1873 profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" name="/run/utmp" pid=7519 comm="cupsd" requested_mask="k" denied_mask="k" fsuid=0 ouid=0

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem.

I seem to have fixed it with the command:

`sudo usermod -a -G lpadmin pi`

This adds the user name pi to the cups user group `lpadmin`.  You can then use the default user name "pi" and password "raspberry" when prompted.

Answer (score 4):

Check if cups is accessible on your localhost through the webinterface

```
Listen localhost:631
WebInterface Yes
```

in */etc/cups/cupsd.conf*. Then restart cups using

```
sudo killall cupsd
sudo /etc/init.d/cups restart
```

and check if you user is part of the group *lpadmin*

```
cat /etc/group | grep YOUR-USERNAME
```

After that you should be able to access cups with you username & pwd on `http://127.0.0.1:631/`

If it still fails check the *cups error log* here

```
tail -f /var/log/cups/error_log
```

P.S. you might also want to read [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2187524).

Comment: I checked everything my Problem still prevails.

Here is my error log output 

        E [23/Jan/2014:14:31:56 +0100] Unable to bind socket for address 127.0.0.1:631 - Address already in use.
E [23/Jan/2014:14:32:27 +0100] Unable to finalize "/etc/cups/subscriptions.conf": No such file or directory
E [23/Jan/2014:14:34:06 +0100] [Client 8] Local authentication certificate not found.

Answer (score 2):

- You can use credentials of any user who is in the `lpadmin` group.
- To see the list of users in `lpadmin` group, use the command in a root shell

  cat /etc/group | grep lpadmin

Answer (score 2):

Just upgraded a bunch of client computers from 14.04 to 16.04 on and ran into this issue.
This appears to be the problem:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cups/+bug/1157318

The fix

```
apt install apparmor-utils
aa-complain /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.cupsd
```

Of course, make sure you really have your user ID in the lpadmin group, as the OP stated.

Answer (score 0):

If you ended up here like me on a newer version, 18.04, you should already be apart of this group.  So your username and password should work.